# Highchart Gauge - Updating With JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts, gauge

I am trying to use highchart gauge. It works properly. But when I want to update it with using ajax, the chart does not change.

```
function (chart) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var strData = "sensor=" + "temperature";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getData.php',
                data: strData,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    point.update(data);
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }, 10000);
```

Just to be sure, I am controlling that does the php part response, with alert function, but it show the correct data. After this part, can not change the point of the chart I think. How can handle this problem?

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: Please post data (your json) here

Comment: I did not get it @Nishith Kant Chaturvedi Do you want php code?

Comment: Try to hardcover some value to pass in update function, to be sure the problem is in update

Comment: When I try to update with point.update(12); it works. But It doesnt allow php file's response.

Comment: I have figured out! var value = parseInt(data); handle the problem. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: alert(data) is 21 and correct, point.update(12) is okey. parsInt(data) is also okay